# Emails not being send when deploying in Vercel (using nodemailer & nodejs/express)

Tags: node.js, express, mern, vercel, nodemailer

I am here today with a back-end problem.
I created an API using nodejs/express/mongoDB. For the account creation I implemented a two factor authetication, using emails (you receive the link to finish creating your account).
For the emails sending I am using nodemailer and Brevo, when testing my code in the localhost everything works fine, the emails are send with no delay and no error are shown. When deploying to Vercel (I also tried Heroku), the API and the front end work perfectly as it was suppose to be. But when I create an account the emails are not being send, no errors are shown.

## Signup function (used in the endpoint)

```
exports.signup = catchErrorAsync(async (req, res) => {
  //Create and hash code
  const token = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

  //Create user
  const user = await User.create(req.body);

  //Create Token doc
  await Token.create({
    userId: user.id,
    token,
  });

  //Send email with code //CHECK WHICH URL TO USE WHEN FRONT IS IMPLEMENTED
  new Email(
    user,
    `https://techworld-jobs.vercel.app/verify-email/${token}`
  ).verifyAccount();

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Email sent.',
  });
});
```

## My email class

(just the part where I send the email)

```
newTransporter() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      return nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.MAILTRAP_HOST,
        port: process.env.MAILTRAP_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.MAILTRAP_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.MAILTRAP_PASSWORD,
        },
      });
    } else {
      return nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.BREVO_HOST,
        port: process.env.BREVO_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.BREVO_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.BREVO_PASSWORD,
        },
        secure: true,
      });
    }
  }

  //send email
  async sendEmail(subject, html) {
    //Define options
    const emailOptions = {
      from: this.from,
      to: this.to,
      subject: subject,
      text: html,
      html: html,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: `application.pdf`,
          content: this.file,
        },
      ],
    };

    //Send email
    await this.newTransporter().sendMail(emailOptions);
  }
```

En theory when creating an account as mentioned before, the email should be send. But when the API is hosted it doesn't.
Hope someone can help me out! Have a great day!